# Does Facebook allow a user to give my app access to their friends email addresses?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am building an app that requires a user to give me access to their Facebook friends. The app is working. However, I have a problem: does Facebook allow a person to give my app access to their friends' email addresses?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **NO**

You can see this in the permissions [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I really hope they don't.

If they did, and a friend of mine used your app, I could probably sue them under the UK data protection act.

Comment: Well, you are probably right (even though I don't know what the UK data protection act is). BUT if they will (I'm sure they won't), they will update their terms in a way you can't use any law against them. (you can always vote against any change based on the Amendments in the terms page).